# Why nextjs is flickering?

Tags: next.js

And so, I have pages on the site that flicker in a strange way. I'll describe what happens:

1. The page appears for a split second.
2. The white screen disappears and is replaced.
3. The rendered page appears.

I would like to get rid of the glare of the page at the very beginning.
And wait until the information is completely loaded. And then render the page. Without any preloaders

```
const AnyPage = ({anyData}) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {anyData}
      </div>
    </section
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const anyData = await loadSomeData();

  return { props: {anyData} } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the data you are getting dose not change very much you can you getStaticProps like this

```
const YourComponent = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>{data}</div>
  )
}


export default YourComponent

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('your api url');
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props:{
            data
        },
        revalidate:60 
       // using revalidate will help the data stay refreshing
    };
}
```

and if data change so much and you want it in real time always user the getServerSideProps

```
const YourComponent = ({ anyData }) => {
    return (
        <div>{anyData}</div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // this is the right way to fecth data in getServerSideProps
    const res = await fetch(`your api url`); 

    const data = await res.json();

    return {
        props: {
          anyData:data
        },
    }
}
```